# Check Network requests happening from iPad without any proxy setting changes

Tags: ios, mac, network

Can we check network requests of an application whose bundle identifier is known?

**Note:** Application is not created by us - its from another third party. We don't have code we just have ipa and we have installed it on iPad.

I am aware of Charles and other third parties that use proxies. In my case I don't have admin rights and we dont want to play with proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Mac as well, you can use **Debookee** to analyze traffic from other devices in your subnet (e.g. an iOS device), even encrypted connections.

https://debookee.com

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do so directly on the iPad without using a proxying or VPN app such as Charles.

Instead you'll need to use tools on the network itself to inspect and check the network request from your app. You can use standard tools such as a PC/Mac with Wireshark connected to the same ethernet segment to inspect the packages. Note that most apps today use encrypted communication. As it is your own app, you might have the option to disable encryption or you have the encryption keys from the server, so that you can decrypt traffic within Wireshark.